# Angular2 rest calls in background

Tags: node.js, angular

i just created sample application as per **jhon papa**'s example.(quick start program).
i designed service class to get json data from my rest service **http://localhost:8081//Myserver/rest/heros**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response , Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { Code } from './code';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }
           private heroesUrl = 'http://localhost:8081//Myserver/rest/heros';  // URL to web api


    getHeroes() {
        return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
            .toPromise()
            .then(
            response => response.json() as Hero[])
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    getHero(id: number) {
        return this.getHeroes()
            .then(heroes => heroes.find(hero => hero.id === id));
    }

    private handleError(error: any) {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

The service class is working fine and heroes are listed in UI as well(just forget about CROS orgin problem here). But one-thing i noticed here the rest call to **http://localhost:8081//Myserver/rest/heros** is directly sent from browser(i can see it in network tab of Developer tool).

According to my application it should not send from browser, instead it should processed over like backend bean classes in JSF and then serve data to relevant Component. i belive this will resolve my CROS orgin problem as well. Dose Angular2 has such option ? Please suggest the right way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebWorkers to move code execution out of the main UI thread. Angular2 provides direct support for that (experimental).

I doubt that will change anything in regard to CORS.
For CORS to work, your server needs to respond with the correct CORS headers.

See also http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/web-workers-in-angular-2.0

Comment: - Thanks for ur quick response, pls clarify my questions.

Comment: - Will all other components also processed by WebWorker ?

Comment: I haven't done much but AFAIK the UI thread runs just the rendering and all other code runs in the WebWorker. Binding data and events are passed between UI thread and WebWorker thread (everything fully transparent).

Comment: - Do we need to separate registraion for each method ?

Comment: You just need to bootstrap your application twice, once for WebWorker and once for the UI thread. Otherwise you don't need to do much as long as you work according to the Angular2 guidelines (not directly accessing the DOM - this can still be done but needs additional work).